# Vue need to update data in created method twice but only first is working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that gets some data in the created hook it looks something like

```
axios.get('/all')
.then(res => {
    this.rows = res.data.table
    axios.post('/names', { array from GET/all })
    .then(res => {
        this.rows.users = res.data.data
    })
})
```

The issue I am having is that the Vue template is showing the data from the first time I set this.rows I have checked with a console.log just below where I set this.rows.users and it is putting the correct data there. What am I missing that prevents my template from outputting the correct data?

Answer (score 1):

You could try updating them together and reduce renders and also prevent chaining promises if they do not depend on each other.

The below code should work

```
Promise.All([axios.get('/all'),axios.post('/names')]) //executes them parallely
  .then(([rowsRes,usersRes]) => {
    this.rows = {...rowsRes.data.table, users: usersRes.data.data}
});
```

**Update**

You could try

```
axios.get('/all')
.then(res => {
    this.rows = res.data.table
    axios.post('/names', { array from GET/all })
    .then(res => {
        this.rows = {...this.rows, users: res.data.data} // do not mutate inner keys which can cause change detection issues.
    })
})
```

Comment: The second can only run after the first has ran. `Promise.All` I don't think will work because of it. I'll edit the OP to make that clearer

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, tried to make it clearer now.

Comment: can you try this ?

Comment: Just gave that a shot and the chrome console says that it is not able to spread a non-iterable array as well as when I do a `console.log(this.rows.users)` I get the correct names back though they are sorted. Starting to think I might be better off to send this to the backend to be dealt with instead of fighting Vue on it.

Comment: maybe rows has a cyclic structure making it non iterable; which could be all the more reason, the vue change detection did not work as expected